# how to avoid ssh asking permission?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

We are attempting to speed up the installation of oracle nodes for RAC installation.
this requires that we get ssh installed and configured so that it doesn't prompt for a password.

The problem is:
On first usage, we are prompted for

```
RSA key fingerprint is 96:a9:23:5c:cc:d1:0a:d4:70:22:93:e9:9e:1e:74:2f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Is there a way to avoid that or are we doomed to connect at least once on every server from every server manually?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Update December 2019:

As Chris Adams pointed out below, there has been a fairly significant change to Openssh in the 6.5 years since this answer was written, and there is a new option that is much safer than the original advice below:

```
* ssh(1): expand the StrictHostKeyChecking option with two new
   settings. The first "accept-new" will automatically accept
   hitherto-unseen keys but will refuse connections for changed or
   invalid hostkeys. This is a safer subset of the current behaviour
   of StrictHostKeyChecking=no. The second setting "off", is a synonym
   for the current behaviour of StrictHostKeyChecking=no: accept new
   host keys, and continue connection for hosts with incorrect
   hostkeys. A future release will change the meaning of
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no to the behaviour of "accept-new". bz#2400
```

So instead of setting `StrictHostKeyChecking no` in your `ssh_config` file, set `StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new`.

---

Set `StrictHostKeyChecking no` in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file, where it will be a global option used by every user on the server.  Or set it in your `~/.ssh/config` file, where it will be the default for only the current user.  Or you can use it on the command line:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l "$user" "$host"
```

Here's an explanation of how this works from [`man ssh_config`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5&manpath=OpenBSD+3.4)
(or see [this more current version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html)):

> **`StrictHostKeyChecking`**
>
>     If this flag is set to “yes”,
>     **ssh**
>     will never automatically add
>                    host keys to the
>     `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`
>     file, and refuses to
>                    connect to hosts whose host key has changed. 
>       This provides maximum protection
>       against trojan horse attacks, however, can be
>                    annoying when the
>     `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`
>     file is
>       poorly maintained,
>       or connections to new hosts are frequently made.  This
>                    option forces the user to manually add all new hosts.  If this
>                    flag is set to “no”,
>     **ssh**
>     will automatically add new host keys to
>                    the user known hosts files.  If this flag is set to “ask”, new
>                    host keys will be added to the user known host files only after
>                    the user has confirmed that is what they really want to do, and
>     **ssh**
>     will refuse to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. 
>                    The host keys of known hosts will be verified automatically in
>                    all cases.  The argument must be “yes”, “no” or “ask”.  The
>                    default is “ask”.

Comment: +1, I also this for my servers. And just to be clear, the message in the question comes from the ssh client on the connecting client computer and not from the server.

Comment: This answer sounds like a security problem in the making.

Comment: This answer is a security hole waiting to happen unless you are careful to only enable it on networks which are known to be safe (i.e. it is never a good idea to have it in `~/.ssh/ssh_config`). Modern versions of OpenSSH support `StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new` which automatically accepts a key from a new host without disabling security checks for every host which you've already connected to.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, @ChrisAdams.   I've added an update to the answer to reflect this new (compared to the date of the original answer) option.

Answer (score 31):

`ssh-keyscan` - Gather ssh public keys

If you already know the list of hosts you will connect to, you can just issue:

```
ssh-keyscan host1 host2 host3 host4
```

You can give the `-H` option to have it hash the results like ssh defaults to now

Also you can give `-t keytype` were *keytype* is `dsa`, `rsa`, or `ecdsa` if you have a preference as to which type of key to grab instead of the default.

Once you have run `ssh-keyscan` it will have pre-populated your known-hosts file and you won't have ssh asking you for permission to add a new key.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled about the "will have pre-populated" comment... known_hosts isn't created or modified after running this. You mean the contents can be piped to the file to populate it?

Comment: Confirming with https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-add-an-ssh-fingerprint-to-your-knownhosts-file-in-linux/ .  `ssh-keyscan -H myhost >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, or for server-wide, `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`

Answer (score 18):

## Ignore Host

Ignore the HostKeyChecking. For this I use e.g.:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null user@example.net
```

## Add Host

Add the host's/server's fingerprint to `.ssh/known_hosts` prior to your first connect. This is the safer way.

Comment: Hi.

Oracle issue the ssh command so I have no control over how it performs this.

Comment: Upvoted. Most of the answers I've seen miss the mentioning of dev nulling the known hosts file. This makes the command much more usable and won't ruin any existent config.

Comment: (2) Sure, adding the fingerprint to the known hosts file is the ideal approach — but *how* does one do it?   (1) Why is it beneficial to set the user known hosts file to `/dev/null`?   Wouldn’t it be better to do `ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.net` once to get the server’s fingerprint into the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file, so subsequent connections will proceed without a request for confirmation?

Answer (score 12):

You can add the fingerprint to each server's known_hosts. For a single user:

```
cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
echo "$SERVER,$PORT ssh-rsa $SERVER_KEY_FINGERPRINT" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: This is no more the right way to do it since when hashing was introduced.

Answer (score 5):

Execute the following snippet before trying.

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh     
echo "Host *" > ~/.ssh/config     
echo " StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

**ps: Strictly not for production servers, beware of ManInMiddle**

Comment: This may (read "usually will") not create the (`.ssh`) directory with mode 700, which I think it needs...?  Add `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` ?

Comment: could you please change the first `echo` to `>>`? otherwise someone running your command will get their pre-existing `.ssh/config` wiped out.

Answer (score 0):

I like Tim's answer for one off type things however, if this is a host you intend on connecting to on a regular basis I would create an entry in your ~/.ssh/config (create it if the file does not exist).

```
# this example shows wildcard for IP
# you can even use more than one wildcard 10.0.*.* for example
Host 192.168.56.*
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
# you can even alias it, which is really useful when scp'ing/rsyncing foo:/path/to/remote
Host foo
    HostName foo-long-192-10-135-55.hostname.not-going-to-remember.doh
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Answer (score -2):

Removed both the all the existing keys from known_hosts and Ran it again. This time the right key has been added and no more having the issue.

Comment: You removed _what_ key from `known_hosts`? The user in the question has not yet connected to the host, so the hosts key would not be there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).