# How to automatically accept fingerprints between two machines after reprovisioning

Tags: ssh, rhel

I have two VMs.

- VM-instance-1
- VM-instance-2

These two connect to each other over `ssh` back and forth for some automate tasks using `user1`.

Issue is that these two gets reprovisioned momentarily and after that we have to manually authenticate fingerprint for ssh to work.

I tried adding `id_rsa.pub` for each of them to other `known_hosts` and persist the known_hosts file to replace the new ones after reprovisioning.

However, the issue is every time while reprovisioning when the new `ssh-keygen` is done it generates new keys, hence the persisting known_hosts is useless.

What can be done for these hosts to remember each other’s and their own fingerprints so we don’t need to manually authenticate fingerprint every time.

Comment: When you talk about accepting fingerprints, do you mean for the SSH *host* keys? `id_rsa.pub` is the user's pubic key, not the host key.

Comment: @muru Yes, then i may be confusing it but I am referring to host keys, the prompt you get when you first time try to ssh.

Comment: You can use `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` for that (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33273/70524). But depending on how you're provisioning the systems, you could also just set the SSH host keys yourself.

Comment: @muru unfortunately since `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` will disable fingerprint checking for all machines so cant do it with that, so how can i set the (same) host keys myself and configure other machine to remember those?

Comment: That depends on how you're provisioning these. If using cloud-init, there's https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#host-keys

Comment: `ssh-keyscan` can collect host keys.